# Wordpress redirection loop error

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I created a website few days back with a url http://abctest.com in wordpress. Now the website has been published to a domain http://www.bcdefg.com.

The server is same, I have not migrated the site, only the domain has been pointed to the same server. I have changed the wphome and wpsite url to respective domain.

What I want to achieve is to redirect all http://abctest.com or http://www.abctest.com requests to http://www.bcdefg.com.

I tried to use .htaccess redirection but that leads to Too many redirection error. Any solution ?

Below is my htaccess code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !bcdefg.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bcdefg.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is on your `rewriteCond` : your host is www.bcdef.com and not bcdef.com (www is important)

try replacing this

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !bcdefg.com$ [NC]`

by this :

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.bcdefg.com$ [NC]`